# Is $ \frac{d}{dt} \Bigg|_{t=0} g e^{-t(X+Y)}e^{tY} = \frac{d}{dt} \Bigg|_{t=0} g e^{-tX} ?$

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Consider the action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication.

Let $g \in G$ an let $X, Y \in \mathfrak{g}$.Then is

$$ \frac{d}{dt} \Bigg|_{t=0} g e^{-t(X+Y)}e^{tY} =  \frac{d}{dt} \Bigg|_{t=0} g e^{-tX} ,$$

even if $[X,Y] \neq 0 ?$

Comment: What do you think? Note that the $g$ in your question is superfluous, so you may as well omit. Then it comes down to the product rule and how to differentiate the exponential function.

Comment: Also, a good way to start thinking about those questions involving Lie algebras/group is to try if it works and how it works for matrix lie groups/algebras. That usually gives some pointers for the more general theory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comments!  Omitting $g$ and applying the product rule I get $\frac{d}{dt} \Bigg |_0 e^{-t(X+Y)} e^{tY} = \frac{d}{dt} \Bigg |_0 e^{-t(X+Y)} + \frac{d}{dt} \Bigg |_0 e^{tY} = -(X+Y) +Y = Y$.

Comment: But If I work with $g$, I'll get $\frac{d}{dt} \Bigg |_0 g e^{-t(X+Y)} e^{tY} =\frac{d}{dt} \Bigg |_0g e^{-t(X+Y)}  + \frac{d}{dt} \Bigg |_0 ge^{tY} $, but, from here I don't know how to continue the computation!

Comment: @Asma . Note that $-(X+Y)+Y=\color{red}{-X}.$ The $g\in G$ is just a constant in that computation as pointed out by the first comment.

Comment: Now, I realize that my question was very trivial. Thanks guys for your help :)

Comment: @Asma:  If you've figured it out, I encourage you to write up your own answer to the question.

Comment: @JasonDeVito, I've posted an answer as you suggested, please take a look !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L_g(h):=gh$ and $R_g(h):=hg$ denote the left and right multiplication on $G$. Applying the following product rule:
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \Bigg|_{t=0}(a(t)b(t)) =dR_{b(0)}\left(a'(t)\right)+dL_{a(0)}\left(b'(t)\right)
$$
to the paths  $a,b:\mathbb{R}\to G$, defined by  $a(t) =L_g(e^{-t(X+Y)})= g.e^{-t(X+Y)}$
and $b(t)= e^{tY}$, we get

$$
\frac{d}{dt} \Bigg|_{t=0} ge^{-t(X+Y)} e^{tY}=dR_{e}\left(dL_g(-(X+Y))\right)+dL_{g}\left(Y\right)
= dL_g(-X) =\frac{d}{dt} \Bigg|_{t=0} ge^{-X},$$
since $dR_e= Id_\mathfrak{g}$ and $dL_g$ is a linear map on $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: Not really (see the comment by @KurtG )

Comment: I don't see where is exactly the fault in my answer , is it in applying the product rule ?

Comment: For what it's worth, I think lcv's answer is incorrect (more specifically, I agree that it's correct for a matrix group, but I don't think it makes sense for a non-matrix group) and that this one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg[e^{-t(X+Y)}e^{tY}\bigg] &=-(X+Y)e^{-t(X+Y)}e^{tY}+e^{-t(X+Y)}e^{tY}Y \\
 &=-e^{-t(X+Y)}(X+Y)e^{tY}+e^{-t(X+Y)}Ye^{tY} \\
 &=-e^{-t(X+Y)}Xe^{tY}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Icv.I'm wondering why is  $e^{tY} Y$ equal to $  Ye^{tY}$ (I know that it holds if $G$ is matrix Lie group, but don't know why it is true for an abstract Lie group) , could you elaborate further please ?

Comment: I don't think this answer is correct for a non-matrix group.  What do you mean by multiplying a Lie algebra element by a Lie group element in general?

Comment: @JasonDeVito, Asma absolutely. This works for matrix groups as suggested by F.Conrad in the comments.